# Global variable not changing between files in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, global-variables

I have kept the global variables in a file and importing this file into two files. One in which the value of this global variable is being changed and another in which this changed value is to be used.

In 1st file , inside a class

```
from globals.py import *
.
.
.class ...
    def uploadClick(self):
        global filename
        filename = dialog.askopenfilename()
        print(filename)
```

In 2nd file

```
from globals.py import *
.
.
.
  def mainAnalysis():
    global filename , semantic_orientation
    print("filename = "+filename)
    n_docs=0
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        count_all = Counter()
```

In globals file

```
filename =''
```

The `mainAnalysis` function is called after the `uploadClickfunction`.

I get an error saying the `filename` is empty when `mainAnalysis` function runs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax `from globals.py import *` makes copies of the variables within `globals.py` into your local file. To access the variables themselves without making copies, `import globals` and use the variable directly: `globals.filename`. You no longer need the `global` keyword if you access the variable this way.